# How to implement escrow like feature like zomato or amazon marketplace

Tags: stripe-payments, e-commerce, marketplace, escrow

How zomato or amazon are storing the buyer money and when the product is delivered the money is send to the seller, how can we do it.

I know to get money from client to my stripe account or razorpay , but how can we store the buyer money and need to transfer it.

How can we implement this escrow in nodejs or any other.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Stripe, you can leverage Stripe [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) to create a platform and payout your merchants. Depending on which [Charge Type](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges) you end up choosing, we recommend to create a specific type of Connect Accounts. For example, if Direct Charges is what it suits your business model the most then you need to create Standard Accounts, whereas for most of the other Charte Types we recommend using Express.

Comment: In India, I think stripe connect is not supported?

Comment: https://support.stripe.com/questions/stripe-india-support-for-marketplaces